# Error 404 in Angular 4 HTTP Request

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried searching for answers in the already asked similar questions but failed to resolve the problem

I am new to Angular 4 and trying to make a simple Angular frontend for a hypothetical book store. There is a hard-coded dataset present in the app as books.json. But the problem is every time to try to run it I get the following error:

[image: Error showing in the ChromeSo, Console]

And here's the screenshot of the project directory and the code.

[image]

Here is my book.service.ts code :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { IBook } from './book';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class BookService {

  constructor(private _http: Http){}

  getBooks(): Observable<IBook[]> {
    return this._http
    .get("api/books/books.json")
    .map((response : Response) => {
      return response.json() as IBook[];
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular. Resource `api/books/books.json` is simply not there. Check your path.

Comment: Don't we need to give the location with respect to the index.html file?

Comment: **No!** Most files are processed and moved to `www/` folder. Contents of `assets/` folder are simply copied over to `www/` so this would be the best place to put your `.json` files. If you move your `.json` to `assets/` you should then access it with `assets/api/books/books.json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move your `api` folder under `root` folder.  In this case under `book-store`.

The issue was not in the code. its about finding the path to the json file is invalid

**Or**

you can keep the files under `src` folder and add the `api` into `assets` in `angular-cli.json`

```
 "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "api"
 ],
```

Comment: Or better yet. Move it to `src/assets/` as this seems to be an asset.

Comment: I tried doing that. But still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to move the json files to the `src/assets` folder. A better solution would be to edit `angular-cli.json` and add your folder (route) to `apps.assets`:

```
"assets": [
    "api",
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
]
```

Now the json files should be accessible, you don't need to change any code. Don't forget to stop serving the application and run `ng serve` again.

Comment: Tried doing that, but still getting the same error. Don't I need to give the location with respect to the index.html file?

Comment: My bad, don't move the `api` folder; keep it inside `src`. This should work as I got it working locally. Don't forget to stop serving the application and run `ng serve` again.

Answer (score 1):

Your folder structure seems ok. The problem is that your server does not know anything about `api` folder. In your `.angular-cli.json`, put `"api"` to your `assets` array like following

```
 ...
 "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "api"
 ],
 ...
```